# formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage and cookies not working on IE11 and Chrome on iPad

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, .net-4.0, session-cookies

When the user try to Login with IE11 he get's "400 bad request"

Other users get's sign out when doing post back actions

More information:

- Server time date is correct and set to UTC timezone.
- The problem also happens when using IP (not only with DNS)
- running on .Net 4 for several months (problem started in the last month)
- IE 10-7 works fine

My code on login:

```
  if (Membership.ValidateUser(strUserName, strPswrd))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(strUserName, chkRememberMe.Checked); 
        }
```

from web.config

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="MyAuthCookie" loginUrl="HomePage.aspx" defaultUrl="Loading.aspx" timeout="9480" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
    </authentication>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution:

Add cookieless="UseCookies" for your forms element in web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FormsAuthenticationOnASPNETSitesWithTheGoogleChromeBrowserOnIOS.aspx